# Using flow with document.querySelector

Tags: dom, flowtype

I'm new to Flow and am having a bit of trouble assigning to DOM Element  types properly.

Looking at the [DOM declarations](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.44.1/lib/dom.js) in the Flow repo, it feels like I'm missing something.

```
// Works 
const otherMeta:?HTMLMetaElement = document.querySelector("meta");

//Doesn't work
const metaTag:?HTMLMetaElement = document.querySelector("meta[name='something']");
```

The second example results in the following error:

```
const metaTag:?HTMLMetaElement = document.querySelector("meta[name='something']");
                                 ^ HTMLElement. This type is incompatible with
const metaTag:?HTMLMetaElement = document.querySelector("meta[name='something']");
               ^ HTMLMetaElement
```

Have a look at [the example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVxhgOpwE4DWAzqgMZwB2RALmHNQBYCmeAsk9QIYBcA-ABIAVVgBl2XAKIwmAWyYVaAXjAATOKQCuchQDoAjhpYBPAMpNppavgAUAIjldbASgDc6TABE4TIhQDktAj4BGSUNGAOnIKcAOZ8QqLinFKy8kqq6lpp+oZ4puZMljb2HJwA2hSccop+RHAODACWFDF+ALrOLkA) in the Try Flow REPL tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flow is not smart enough to know what the return type will be for an arbitrary `querySelector` query. The simple element-name queries have been hard-coded into the builtin type definitions. You can see them in [Flow's Github repo](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/ce611168a5a047a88cf5273322d2dd390ed5aede/lib/dom.js#L734).

For Flow to know that the result is an HTMLMetaElement, you'll need to explicitly verify that with code like

```
const metaTag: ?HTMLElement = document.querySelector("meta[name='something']");
if (metaTag && !(metaTag instanceof HTMLMetaElement)) throw new Error("Expected a 'meta' element.");

// use metaTag here
```

so by explicitly checking `instanceof`, Flow will recognize that `metaTag` *must* now be the type `HTMLMetaElement`. This type of behavior is very common in Flowtype and is referred to as refining the type.